# I want to create gradle script to checkout the code from gitHub as soon as deveoper checkin to repository.?

Tags: github, gradle, build.gradle, gradle-plugin

I can checkout the code from github using import org.ajoberstar.gradle.git.tasks.*
. But I want to check out the code immediately after code checkined to github repository automatically and deploys it into web server.Is there any plugin to identify the commit history in github repo.Or some other ways to do it.

Answer (score 2):

Two options I can think of:

1. Use a [git commit hook](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks) to trigger the gradle task.
2. Periodically poll [git log](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log) to check for new commits (you might be able to use gradle's new [continuous mode](http://gradle.org/feature-spotlight-continuous-build/) to achieve this)

Comment: Wow, I used the first one and I got my solution.